# Webbrowser Silverlight 4 Control and UNC Share

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-4.0, unc

I need  to open documents in the WebBrowser control (SL 4) which is located on a UNC share, i think it's not possible without installing something on the client box... (COM object, physical link...)

What do you think ?

Comment: The documents you want are located on the UNC share?

What have you tried? It may work in an elevated trust SL4 out of browser application, but it shouldn't work in a partial-trust SL4 application.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just map a virtual directory to the UNC share from your web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, as the concept of a UNC share is considered "cross-scheme", similar to how you can't navigate to an http:// page from an https:// served application.

Your only option is to use COM to open the objects directly. This is simple enough using the Windows shell/scripting host, it will be able to send a shell run command for any UNC location that is authenticated.